# Very Very Large Number Python

Tags: python, biginteger

I've searched the databases and cookbooks but can't seem to find the right answer. I have a very simple python code which sums up self powers in a range. I need the last ten digits of this very, very large number and I've tried the getcontext().prec however I'm still hitting a limit.

Here's the code:

```
def SelfPowers(n):
      total = 0
      for i in range(1,n):
          total += (i**i)
      return(total)

print SelfPowers(n)
```

How can I see all those beautiful numbers? It prints relatively fast on my quad-core. This is just for fun for ProjectEuler, Problem #48, no spoilers please I DO NOT WANT THE SOLUTION and I don't want the work done for me, so if you could point me in the right direction please?

Thanks,
mp

Comment: Hint: You don't need to calculate these numbers, just their last 10 digits. So, you can use the number theory equality `mod(a*b, m) = mod(mod(a,m) * mod(b,m), m)` (applied for `m=10^10`)

Comment: @ypercube: and Python makes it real easy by providing `pow(a,b,n)` (equal to `(a**b)%n` but faster).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the *last ten digits* of a number, don't compute the whole thing (it will take too much memory and time).

Instead, consider using the "three-argument" form of `pow` to compute powers mod a specific base, and you will find the problem is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Testing on Python 3.2 I was able to

```
print(SelfPowers(10000))
```

though it took some seconds. How large a number were you thinking?

**Edit:** It looks like you want to use `1000`? In such case, upgrade to Python 3 and you should be fine.